# Is there a more concise regex to match a-z except for characters e, n, p?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to write a regex to match characters a-z except for e, n p. I can write:

```
[a-df-moq-z]
```

I'm just wondering if there's a way to write something like ([a-z except ^enp]) just to make the regex more easy to decipher which characters are excluded.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use negative lookahead like this:

```
(?![enp])[a-z]
```

**Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/1LnJswio3F**

**Explanation:**

- It means match any character in the range of `a-z` except when character is one of `[enp]`.
- `(?![enp])` is a [negative lookahead expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that fails the match when we have letters `e` or `n` or `p` at the next position,

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to do this, depending on which regex flavor you're using.  [@anubhava's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16793134/20938) is the most portable, because it works in any flavor that supports lookaheads.

If you want to match a whole word or a whole string, you need to wrap that regex in a group, forcing the regex engine to treat the whole thing as one atom:

```
/\b(?:(?![enp])[a-z])+\b/

/^(?:(?![enp])[a-z])+$/
```

Another possibility is to scan the whole word/string to make sure it doesn't contain any of the unwanted characters, and then match it in the usual way:

```
/\b(?!\w*[enp])[a-z]+\b/

/^(?!\w*[enp])[a-z]+$/
```

It's all pretty hackish, but in JavaScript it's what you're stuck with.  Some of the other flavors provide tools specifically for this purpose, like set intersection (Java, Ruby 1.9.x):

```
[a-z&&[^enp]]
```

..or set subtraction (.NET):

```
[a-z-[enp]]
```

The [Unicode Consortium](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Subtraction_and_Intersection) has gone hog wild with all this set arithmetic stuff, but as far as I know no real-world regex flavor has come anywhere near implementing all of its proposals.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[^[^a-z]enp]` which works but is a bit confusing to understand.

`[^a-z]enp` defines a class that includes all characters that are not a-z and adds e, n and p. Then by inverting that class you get a class that matches a-z except e, n, and p.

You can try it here http://www.rubular.com/r/VEZNFgxgfI

**Update**: But it seems to not work in JavaScript (tested Chrome). Ruby and PCRE should work.

Comment: In javascript it only works if you use a defined group, like `\W`. I.e. `[^\Wenp]`